How to add debug to log file and remove log lines in console
import logging
import datetime
import requests
import warnings
def log_file(log_name):
    log_day = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    log_name = '/sample1/log_basics/' + log_day + "_" + log_name
    return log_name


logging.basicConfig(filemode='a', format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s',level=logging.DEBUG)

i = "_developertest_log"
logger = logging.getLogger(i)
logger.propagate=False
log_name = i + ".log"
handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file(log_name))
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)

def process2(abc):
    print("Going to check: "+str(abc))
    logger.info("Going to check test1: "+str(abc))
    x = requests.get('https://w3schools.com/python/demopage.htm')
    print(x.text)

abc = "68485"
process2(abc)

Is there any solution to add """2024-04-02 11:42:05,369:DEBUG:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): w3schools.com:443""" debug line in log file and dont need to show log lines in the output console

Does this answer your question? How to write to a file, using the logging Python module?

@Tzane I need to add debug line to log file and log line should not be able to visible in console output.. I cannot find in that forum..

Does this answer your question? How to set logging level for the module only in Python?

When you wrote logging.basicConfig(..., level=logging.DEBUG) you set the log level for the root logger. The log you see in the console is coming from the requests module.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I dont need to see the log in console.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I have added logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) but the debug line is not coming in log file and still the log lines are showing in console

You want to remove that logging.basicConfig line or pass in the handlers you want to be used with the root logger...

@AbdulAzizBarkat I have removed logging.basicConfig and tried handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) but the debug lines are not included in log file

The reason(s) this doesn't work is a mix of things: while you specify a "filemode" for logging.basicConfig, you never tell the root logger to write to any files. And actually, this is not even a mistake (apart from setting a filemode when you don't need it), since it's considered not so good practice to use the root logger as your logger in this way. However, the logger you create with logger = logging.getLogger(i), has no relation to the requests module and therefore only handles the manual call to logger.info("...") while the log messages coming from the requests module (actually urllib3 in there), are being handled by the root logger, whom you have told to display debug-level messages via the standard StreamHandler with your: logging.basicConfig(filemode='a', format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s',level=logging.DEBUG) - which means they are displayed in the console.
So it's a bit of a mix of things you need to untangle. You have many choices here, but let me give you a simple one:
The relevant lines:
# 1. create a handler and set its filemode to append
handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file(log_name),mode='a')
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s'))

# 2. create a logger that you'll use as you please
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(handler)

# 3. create a logger that captures the requests modules log messages
requests_logger = logging.getLogger("urllib3")
requests_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_logger.addHandler(handler)

Note that technically, you can do without the logger and do your "logger.info("Going to check test1..." instead with requests_logger, but I personally find it better to differentiate between logs coming directly from a module and those that you set manually in the code. Furthermore, if you want to differentiate between those messages in the log file, you have a bunch of choices again -
For instance:
) Adapt your Formatter to include the pathname the message originated from:
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(pathname)s:%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s'))

) Or, create different handlers with different formatters for each logger you need and write to the same file (and then add the correct handler to the corresponding logger)
) Or, write to specific log files per logger you set up
